get error after finish bigbluebutton installation
I Installed Bigbluebutton on Ubuntu 20.4 Server, After Finish installation when I checked the domain get this error :
500 Internal Server Error
If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.
who can help me to fixed error
I checked the ufw status on my server and allow the 80,443,22/tcp port and 1616384:32768/udp allowed
